# Why does my abs lights stay on 90percent of the time but when they do go off I know know that the next time I brake I'm going to slide all over road

Tags: nissan, lights, abs, sentra

I just bought a car and now I won't drive it because I'm scared at this point....my ABS lights stay on all the time except every now and then when I'm driving they will go off but when this happens the next time I use my brakes the car slides all over not much control at all almost like my brakes lock up then let go but it throws me all over the road when this happens. I will hear a clicking sound as well when the lights shut off and when I brake it makes me skid across road twices everytime then the abs lights come right back on and everything is fine again until next time.. why is this happening and isn't it kinda backwards the way the lights stay on being a good thing but when they turn off it's bad brake time. Sorry if this is kinda confusing but I don't know any other way to explain it and I don't know what to do no one seems to know but I've gotten to flats in back within a month and now sharp metal is sticking out back tire. the car is a 2011 Nissan Sentra

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you talked to the dealership you bought this from? Was there any warranty behind the vehicle? When you say the"metal is sticking out", where is it sticking out? Can you add pictures to your post to show what you mean? Have you had the ABS codes read to see what's going on? If so, what are those codes?

Comment: Was this car bought "as is" from a private seller? Autozone performs free reading of emissions and abs error codes. Call ahead to ask if your 2011 Nissan Sentra abs error code(s) are decodable with their reader.

Comment: On some cars the ABS warning light doubles as a "low brake pad" warning. If you are having braking problems, take the car to a shop right away.